# Search lists inside dictionaries from API request

Tags: python

I'm trying to query a dictionary with a list and another dictionary inside. I'm using the deck of cards API and want to pull the value out.

```
drawCard='https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/vx58tedq5moe/draw/?count=1'

response = requests.get(drawCard)
getValue = json.loads(response.text)
value= (getValue['cards'])
print (getValue)
print("")
print("")
print (value)
card= (getValue['cards'](''))
```

This is what I get when I print getValue.

```
{'deck_id': 'vx58tedq5moe', 'success': True, 'cards': [{'suit': 'SPADES', 'code': '0S', 'value': '10', 'images': {'png': 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/0S.png', 'svg': 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/0S.svg'}, 'image': 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/0S.png'}], 'remaining': 44}
```

I narrowed it down to this using getValue['cards'] but cant go any further.

```
[{'suit': 'SPADES', 'code': '0S', 'value': '10', 'images': {'png': 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/0S.png', 'svg': 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/0S.svg'}, 'image': 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/0S.png'}]
```

I want to grab the 10 from value

Comment: I get this error when I do that "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of getValue['cards'] is a list, so first you want to access the list element, `getValue['cards'][0]` then you can access the element 'value' with

`getValue['cards'][0]['value']`

If you want to get all value from all cards in the list of cards, you can use list comprehension to do something like

`[c['value'] for c in getValue['cards']]`

Answer (score 0):

You go multiple levels down like this:

```
value= (getValue['cards']['value'])
```

BC 'cards' is the key to the list and 'value' is key to the value in the list witch have the value of 10.

Comment: This is not correct because ```getValue['cards']``` returns a list of dictionaries so you need to index into the list before you can access ```['value']```